# JsonResults with DbSet

Tags: c#, json

I was wondering if there was a way to combine these two. There are two multiple db sets. I've already tried putting with the same variable. Any ideas?

```
     public JsonResult GetProductByPDLN(int pdlnId, int copcCode) 
        {
            _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var prod = _context.ProductLines
                .Where(pl => pl.Id == pdlnId)
                .Select(p => p.Products)
                .ToList();
            var copc = _context.ProfitCenters
                .Where(c => c.Id == copcCode)
                .Select(p => p.ProductLines)
                .ToList();
            return Json(prod && copc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean to combine? Do you need to return two separate sets or one? In this case you need to show you db tables with relations  and tell us what data  do you need to return.

Answer (score 1):

Either create a new class or an anonymous. Something along these lines:

```
     public JsonResult GetProductByPDLN(int pdlnId, int copcCode) 
    {
        _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var prod = _context.ProductLines
            .Where(pl => pl.Id == pdlnId)
            .Select(p => p.Products)
            .ToList();
        var copc = _context.ProfitCenters
            .Where(c => c.Id == copcCode)
            .Select(p => p.ProductLines)
            .ToList();
        return Json(new {ProductLines = prod, ProfitCenters = copc}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```